# Disabling Spring Related Vault Check

Tags: spring-boot, hashicorp-vault

I have a Vault Post Processor that is ordered as the lowest precedence in Spring. I do not want "vault":{"status":"UP"}

Appearing in the health check. I've searched around and found a lot of people recommending turning this to false:

```
management:
  health:
    vault:
      enabled: false
```

In the boostram.yml (or Application.yml) after updating and restarting my app neither of these have ended up removing the vault check from the health check. Is there a separate config that I should be updating?

Comment: For people willing to keep usage of vault but just disabling the health check, I tried with this configuration and it works, so have a look on your config file to make sure it was well formatted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out i was using a spring-vault-starter dependency in my pom.xml. After removing that I no longer saw the vault checks in the health check!